# How do I fly as a Pteranodon in Primal Carnage?

Tags: primal-carnage

I have seen other players fly as a Pteranodon in Primal Carnage. How do you do that?

There is a video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FH18RDp67uY) for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Simply hold the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> button to run, then press and hold the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key while running. Your ptera will jump, and then flap into the air, automatically."

Reference: [Primal Carnage Forum](http://www.primalcarnage.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=5582).